# Body empty in response php from database because special character

Tags: php, flutter

i can't resolve my problem with special character, in my case "à". When i open my php file in browser, if the special character is include in database on a table with varchar utf8_general_ci the response is empty, but if i delete this character the response is normal. Could you help my please. Thank you in advance

Here my php code

```
<?php

include('connec.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles";

$result = $link->query($sql);

$myarray = array();

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $myarray[] = $row;
    }
    // Send back the complete records as a json
    echo json_encode($myarray);
}else{
    echo "error";
}
$link->close();

return;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your PHP file doesn't return anything there might be a simple error in it. There are two ways to check this:

1. Check the [PHP error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel). These are text files containing all the errors generated by your code.
2. [Switch on error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). This will output any error, **except syntax errors!** For those errors you need to check the logs. This is how you switch on error reporting:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: i don't have any error in php error log, and if i change the name of table to do a error, i have an error in php error log

Comment: i'm using wamp to emulating ther application

Comment: @BabaBoy Could you have a look at the source code of your web page to see if it is truly empty. Sometimes a page may look blank, but it is only because a character cannot be rendered. Next you could add the normal HTML code, see: [HTML5 Template](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-basic-html5-template/). It's long, but it explains everything. You can skip the CSS and JS. Finally, if there's still nothing, you could add a bit of extra feedback in the code. I usually do things like `echo "Step 1<br>";`, `echo "Step 2<br>";` and so on, on each line so I can see which lines get executed.